# ffmpeg fade in animation and logo overlay in a single step

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following commands to create a fade in effect with a series of images and then place a water mark png using the lut filter on the generated video:

//Creating the fade in video:

```
ffmpeg -t 5 -i 1.jpg -t 5 -i 2.jpg -t 5 -i 3.jpg -t 5 -i 4.jpg -i 5.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0];[1:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1];[2:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2];[3:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3];[4:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v4];[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuva444p[v]" -map "[v]" -s "480x600" -t 40 series_out_fade_v2_5images.mp4
```

After the video is created I use the following command to place a water mark logo over it:

//Water mark

```
ffmpeg -y -i series_out_fade_v2_5images.mp4 -i optimaken_logo.png -filter_complex "[1]lut=a=val*0.5[a];[0][a]overlay=0:0" -c:v libx264 -an v4_output.mp4
```

my questions are:

1. **How can I achieve both in a single command**

   2. **How do I scale overlay proportionally so that the height of the water mark is always 65 pixels and the width is scaled
      proportionally**
   3. **Explicitly tell where to place the logo to the top right corner with a padding of 10 pixels for both x and y**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i 1.jpg -i 2.jpg -i 3.jpg -i 4.jpg -i 5.jpg -i optimaken_logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125:s=480x600,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0];[1:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125:s=480x600,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1];[2:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125:s=480x600,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2];[3:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125:s=480x600,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3];[4:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125:s=480x600,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v4];[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[v];[5]scale=-1:65,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[a];[v][a]overlay=W-w-10:10" -t 40 series_out_fade_v2_5images.mp4
```

`colorchannelmixer` should be faster than `lut`.

Comment: Works perfectly...Thanks @Gyan. Only one thing...I am getting this message:
`[swscaler @ 000001e04fd4d040] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
`

Comment: You can ignore that. Old message, not really relevant anymore.